# Regular expression to preserve line breaks

Tags: php, regex, line-breaks

I have a regular expression which allows only certain characters in the message.
What I'm trying to achieve is to **allow line breaks** as well which will be preserved using **nl2br** function.

That's what I have so far:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9ńśćółęążź\ .,-]/','',$message)
```

As far as I have checked, the following expression should preserve line breaks but I'm having problems adding it to the above expression:

```
/(\r|\n|\r\n){2,}/
```

Comment: I would break the string and check each line, instead of including the line breaks to the regex expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just want to add `\r` & `\n` to the list of characters to not replace. So:

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9ńśćółęążź\ \.,\-\r\n]/",'',$message)
```

In the above expression I've also had to change the `'` to " (so that `\r` & `\n` are recognised) but have also had to escape the `.` and `-` characters

Comment: Also need add **Global flag**: /[^a-zA-Z0-9ńśćółęążź\ \.,\-\n\r]/g

Comment: There's no `g` modifier in PHP

Comment: yes, you're right) preg_replace() will perform global replacements by default, and **g** is not a valid modifier in PCRE (the regex implementation PHP uses)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

- use preg_quote to avoid forgetting to escape certain characters, like the "." in your expression. I'm sure that mostly broke it.
- Use the case insensitive 'i' modifier, instead of a-zA-Z
- as Ross said, add \r and \n

> print preg_replace('/' . preg_quote('[^a-z0-9ńśćółęążź\ .,-\r\n])') .
>   '/i','',"test\r\ntest\rtest\ntest");